# load R Environment.RData for shiny server

Tags: r, shiny

I just hosted my first shiny app on a droplet web server and things appear to be only partially functional.

This is because the data that loaded into R on my PC when i developed the shiny app is not being read in to the Shiny app hosted on the server.  The data is available in the form of an `Environment.RData` file. This `Environment.RData` file needs to be loaded into R for the shiny app to have access to all of the data needed.

I am struggling to add the correct line of code to load this `Environment.RData` file.

I have tried some of the most obvious options (shown below) but without success...

```
#server.R
    load("~/srv/shiny-server/Shiny_scRNASeq/R_Environment.RData")
    load("R_Environment.RData")
    source('R_Environment.RData', local=TRUE)
```

I have tried several iterations of similar commands but without success.

Does anyone know of another way to load this `R_Environment.RData` file or do i need to go back and individually add the datasets used by the functions in the shiny app.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had success including my data as .rds files.  First step was saving with `saveRDS()` to `data/`, and then loading in `server.R` with `asdf <- readRDS("data/asdfasdf.rds")`.

I'm not sure how to go about this with an `Environment.RData` file, but this might get you what you need if there aren't too many objects to deal with.

Comment: Although this was a bit cumbersome due to a large number of datasets it did work!  Thank you.